# Angular $http POST to target="_blank"

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I need to make a `POST` from Angular to a URL `./makeFile.php` which will create a file with contents from a database query based on the information provided in that `POST` data.

PHP forces the browser to open a save dialog rather than just displaying the response with these 2 lines:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '.prj"');
echo $json;
```

But making a `POST` from AngularJS using `$http` forces the browser to not open this save dialog:

```
   $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: './makeFile.php',
      data: {
        project: ProjectService.getProject()
      }
    })
```

I can't make a `GET` because the data is too long for a URL, otherwise I would replace it with a simple `$window.open('./makeFile.php', '_blank')` which works in (the rare) case of small data.

How do I make Angular make this `POST` to another window or let the browser open the save dialog?

**Edit:**

As Ivan suggested, I had to programatically create a form to achieve what I want. Here's how I did it:

JavaScript:

```
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.action = './php/saveProject.php';
    form.method = 'POST';
    form.target = '_blank';
    form.style.display = 'none';

    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'text';
    input.name = 'project';
    input.value = angular.toJson(ProjectService.getProject(), false);

    var submit = document.createElement('input');
    submit.type = 'submit';
    submit.id = 'submitProject';

    form.appendChild(input);
    form.appendChild(submit);
    document.body.appendChild(form);

    $('#submitProject').click();

    document.body.removeChild(form);
```

PHP:

```
<?php
        $project = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($_POST['project']) : $_POST['project'];

        // ...

        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '.prj"');

        echo $json;

?>
```

Comment: How do you call your `$http` in your app ? Using a model, controller and so on ?

Comment: Display "download" link on success with target="_blank" or window.open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had similar issue, and I couldn't do with with `$http`. So I programatically created html form with `method="post"` and `target="_blank"`. And I placed hidden elements with data I needed to send. After I submitted that form I removed it from dom.

Let me know if you find another solution, using `$http`.

Comment: I believe as you said, it's not possible through `$http`. I followed your suggestion and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I got a similar problem too, http get can do but post cannot do the same.  a form submit may work for me, but HOW can you deal with the response from the post request? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an example of how did you achieve this? I have tried this and it is always GET request



 <form [formGroup] = "myForm" method="post" > 

          <a  class="anchInfo" href='https://www.myownurl.com' target="_blank" >click here</a>

       </form>

Comment: You should put target="_blank" inside form, not in link. And it won't work if it's just a link. You must get that click event, prevent default, get form element inside the script, and submit it.

Also, keep in mind that this answer is 5 years old, I am not sure how Angular is working now (not in FE for some time) and if there are better solutions because this one seems kinda hacky now.