# ng-submit, removing a form, and "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"

Tags: angularjs, forms

I'm using angular 1, and trying to set a variable when a form is submitted using ng-click or ng-submit. That variable then cascades and removes the form from the DOM using an ng-if. However, I run into the chrome error message "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected", and the form is not posted.

Here's a complete MWE:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Something</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div ng-if="status.value=='ok'">
        <form action="url" method="post" target="_blank">
          <button type="submit" ng-click="status.value='newwindow'">Open in new window</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div>{{status}}</div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      var ctrl = app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.status = {'value':'ok'};
      }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Whenever I completely remove the ng-* attributes, the form submits normally, but then the variable isn't updated.

Any suggestions on how to keep the form around just long enough to post it?

Comment: A quick Google search suggests that your error is due to the form element not being part of the DOM. Please include all your HTML, and Angular code, for help with debugging.

Comment: I saw that. On first blush, it looked like the form was obviously part of the DOM, but I put together a stripped down version anyway. Having put together a complete MWE, it looks like the ng-* events were actually removing the form before the form posted... see updated question.

Comment: ng-click should refer to a function

Comment: `ng-click` to evaluate an expression is fine, according to [the AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick).

Comment: Not sure what your use case is for this, but try `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`, which just hides the element instead of removing it from DOM.

Comment: @JorgeValle The use case is that this page is usually embedded in an iframe, and uses an Eventsource connection. The purpose of the button is to open the page in a new window (outside of the iframe), but to close the Eventsource connection so that there aren't two such connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code here is the `ng-if` statement.  When you click the button, the `status.value` is updated *immediately*, causing a `$digest` cycle.  The `$digest` cycle causes the `ng-if` to be `false`, which removes the entire `div` (including the form) from the DOM.

One possible fix would be to use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`, which just *hides* the element, but does not remove it from the DOM.

Another possibility would be to attach the `ng-click` to a function which handles all the form submission logic, and perhaps even suppresses the default submission with `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Sigh. It's actually an ng-switch that's changing things in my code (and requires the DOM change), but ng-if made a good case for the MWE. So, no sg-show for me. Sounds like I need to do a manual form submission.

Comment: yeah I don't know of a way to use `ng-switch` and keep the form intact.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion, @Claies. If anybody else needs to do a manual form submit, I found this question to be very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823626/angular-http-post-to-target-blank

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Something</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div ng-if="status.value=='ok'">
        <form action="url" method="post" ng-submit="formSubmit()" target="_blank">
          <button type="submit" ng-click="status.value='newwindow'">Open in new window</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div>{{status}}</div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      var ctrl = app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.status = {'value':'ok'};
$scope.formSubmit=function(){
//here you can write you business logic here
};
      }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

or you can also write:

```
 <form action="url" method="post"  target="_blank">
              <button type="submit" ng-click="postData()">Open in new window</button>
            </form>
```

in your controller:

```
$scope.postData=function(){
//logic will be here:
}
```