# How to call a POST request in new tab in angular with authorization bearer token in header

Tags: post, http-headers, angular5

I am new angular. I am trying to call my rest service on a POST method, which will open a pdf document.

I need to call the POST method in new tab, to get my pdf document from the service layer, with authorization bearer token added in header.

Please suggest some angular way to achieve this.

html

```
<input type="button" value="Generate PDF" (click)="generatePDF();">
```

component.ts

```
generatePDF(){

this.documentService.generatePDF();

}
```

service.ts

```
httpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders(
   {
    'authorization': 'Bearer '+this.accessTolken
  })
};

generatePDF() {

let payLoad = {
  'field1': 'field1',
  'field2': 'field2',
  'field3': 'field3',
  'field4': 'field4',
  'field5': 'field5'
}

const postUrl = `${this.serviceUrl}/pdfbypost`;
this.http.post(postUrl , payLoad,this.httpOptions)
.subscribe();                                           //Need something like this one

window.open(postUrl , "_blank");                         // or this one


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular $http POST to target="\_blank"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823626/angular-http-post-to-target-blank)

Comment: @g33k Edited my question, need to add bearer token in the header.

Comment: Anyone has any solution for this.

Comment: @MPPNBD I am also facing the same issue. did you able to resolve the same?

Comment: No @PrashantAgrawal, I didn't get any solution, for this.